# Using Linux file/directory functions in Nginx module?

Tags: nginx, module

I'm developing an Nginx module, and want to use Linux file/directory functions in the module (such as `readlink` and `access`).
The reasons are: Nginx module API does not support these functions, and actually Nginx module API functions are using Linux file/directory functions internally.

http://agentzh.org/misc/code/nginx/os/unix/ngx_files.c.html#L344

Of course, this must make compatibility issues, but it's not a problem in my case.
Is there any other problems?

Answer (score 0):

I have written quite a few Nginx modules and you can do whatever you want in there. 
You have full control but also full responsibility as Nginx may crash or a process may block on some IO, mutex, etc, so be careful.
Of course when you ./configure your project you have to link with the right libraries but that's all about it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I worry about is Nginx `stability` and `security`. I think : 1) Simple reason such as using Linux file/directory functions will not decrease the Nginx stability and security. 2) If it makes problems, other reasons must be combined. Am I right?

Comment: The stability and security of your module depends only on the way you code it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer again.